# How to rollback Rabbit-mq message after Junit test?

Tags: junit, rabbitmq

When you test your code, you send a message to rabbit-mq. How do you get the message back when the test is over?

```
public interface RabbitProducer {
    String OUTPUT = "rabbitmq_producer_channel";

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}

public class SysGroupServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitProducer rabbitProducer;

    @Override
    public Result remove(Collection<? extends Serializable> idList) {
        rabbitProducer.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(idList)
                .setHeader("x-delay", 5000)
                .setHeader("MessageType", "GroupBatchDelete").build());
        return Result.booleanResult(true);
    }
}

@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Rollback
public class SysGroupServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private SysGroupService sysGroupService;
    @Test
    void removeTest(){
      sysGroupService.remove(Stream.of("1").collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

I use Spring Cloud Stream to be compatible with RabbitMQ, and all the relevant code is there.Is there a way to mock this out?I tried the following scheme, but due to X-dealy, I got this error:No exchange type x-delayed-message

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fridujo</groupId>
        <artifactId>rabbitmq-mock</artifactId>
    </dependency>

@Component
public class RabbitMqMock {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(MockConnectionFactoryFactory.build());
    }
}
```

I know little about mocks. Can mocks create an X-delay exchange?

Comment: are you hitting a real rabbit mq from an unit test? how about mocking the service so you don't depend on the state of external resources?

Comment: Yes, unit tests send a message to Rabbit MQ when they are run.
However, I would prefer not to send a message during unit testing.
Avoid data contamination during unit testing.
My current practice is to turn off the consumer during unit testing and then clear the queue after the testing is complete.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think it's possible to replace the rabbit service with a mock and use that instead. Take a look at mockito library.
If you can share the code/class that calls that service, we may be able to come up with a test strategy.

Comment: The code has been completed at the top. Any good ideas?